# Add class to parent anchor in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i am getting stuck with adding class to parent anchor on click event

**CSS**

```
<style type='text/css'>
.pro_nav li a{
   color:#949494;
}
.pro_nav li a:hover, .pro_nav li a.active{
  color:#ffbe1b;
}
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('.pro_info').hide();
$('.pro_info:first').show();
$('.pro_nav ul li a:first').addClass('active');
$('.pro_nav ul li a').click(function(){
$('.pro_nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active'); // this line not working
var Protab = $(this).attr('href');
$('.pro_info').hide();
$(Protab).fadeIn(1000);
return false;
});
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="pro_nav">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#qa">q&a </a></li>
        <li><a href="#galleries">galleries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#wishlist">wishlist</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I want to apply active class on anchor parents

Comment: What parent anchor? Do you mean parent LI?

Comment: It's not a parent, just do `$(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: its better to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for such type of question.

Comment: Incidentally, when you wrote `$('.pro_nav ul li a:first')`, did you mean `$('.pro_nav ul li:first a')`?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks its working fine please create as answer so i accepted your answer...

Comment: Just accepts Arun's answer, same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the css rule is not specified for the `li` element, it is for the `anchor` element (`.pro_nav li a.active`)

```
$('.pro_nav ul li a').click(function () {
    $('.pro_nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var Protab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.pro_info').hide();
    $(Protab).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vwY5G/)